# How to Use Scope in Facebook Graph API C# sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Before asking this question, I have searched a lot, but did not find a single working example for this.  I want to retrieve the page access token for one of my pages.  I read that scope should be passed as parameter with permission manage_pages.  But its not working.

Here is my code:  http://pastebin.com/GNVimbFX

Answer (score 0):

Basically there's two steps that you need to do

1. Retrieve access_token with manage_pages permission
2. Get /me/accounts which would return you page access_token

You can read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens)

Comment: Oh thanks, actually the result is coming in Json format and I have 3 pages .. as a result i am getting 3 access tokens.... each page is having their own page access token.. but how can I choose the access token for a specific page?

Comment: Either use FQL (Facebook Query Language) or just loop through all of the items received from API and check one by one